# mysql any array sorting problem

Tags: php

I have some users listed below in an order:

user1
user2
user3
user4
user5

This is just a simple list, sorted according to age.

Now a new user (user6) comes in, and according to the sorting, he fits after user 2, so the order becomes like:

user1
user2
**user6**
user3
user4
user5

Now I want to know at which position it is. For example it is on place3.
How can i find its position when a new user comes in the list??
Please tell any general way?
there is no any database etc, just a logic question.

Comment: @moustafa: Does this have anything to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

What does this have to do with MySQL?

Use `array_search($myuser, $users);`

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php .

Comment: Possibly `array_search($myuser, $users) + 1` in this case (he seems to want the index + 1).

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
SELECT count(b.id)+1 row_pos
FROM users a, users b
WHERE
    a.name = 'user6'
    AND a.age > b.age
```

Thus it shows position of your row